# Máscara Plano contábil em javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Como posso fazer uma função em javascript para formatar os valores digitados em um input para o padrão do plano de contas contábil similar ao exposto abaixo.

1 *(min)*
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.1.01
1.1.1.01.001 *(max)*

Coluna **Conta**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função baixo que verifica os 8 dígitos e aplica os pontos "`.`" de acordo com o padrão.

Você precisa colocar `onkeyup="mascara(this)"` no campo que quer mascarar para chamar a função.

**Veja:**

```js
function mascara(i){
   var v = i.value;
   
   // este "if" impede que sejam inseridos
   // outros caracteres que não sejam números
   if(isNaN(v[v.length-1])){
      i.value = v.substring(0, v.length-1);
      return;
   }

   v = i.value.replace(/\./g,"");

   i.value = v[0]
   + (v[1] ? "."+v[1] : '')
   + (v[2] ? "."+v[2] : '')
   + (v[3] ? "."+v[3] : '')
   + (v[4] || '')
   + (v[5] ? "."+v[5] : '')
   + (v[6] || '')
   + (v[7] || '');
}

// Breve explicação:
// v[x] onde "x" é a posição do caractere na string.
// Ex.: v = "foo", logo v[0] = "f", v[1] e v[2] = "o"

// Operadores:
// (v[1] ? "."+v[1] : '')
// Se v[1] for true (existe), retorna "."+v[1];
// senão, retorna '' (vazio)

// (v[4] || '')
// se v[4] for true (existe), retorna ele mesmo,
// senão retorna '' (vazio)
```

```html
<input maxlength="12" type="text" id="numero" onkeyup="mascara(this)" />
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo era isso que eu precisava, mas por gentileza, poderia me explicar essas duas linhas de código pra eu pegar a lógica?  (v[3] ? "."+v[3] : '') + (v[4] || '')

Comment: Coloquei uma explicação no código. Abs!